# How Struts 2 will behave with Spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, spring-security

Usually Struts 2 action instances will get create on the request. I mean per every request new action instance will get create. But if I integrate with Spring then there will be only one action instance will get create (I am not sure correct me if I am wrong).

So in this case what is if I have instance variables in the action class?

First user here will set that instance with some instance variables and second user may set there something. How it will behave at this time?

**More clarification:** Instance variable means, in Struts 2, action forms won't be there so, your action itself work as a form to get the request parameters. First user enters something and second user enters something and both are setting to one instance action.

Answer (score 0):

If your actions are managed by Struts container, then Struts is creating them in the `default` scope.

If your actions are managed by Spring container, then you need to define the scope of the action beans, because Spring by default uses `singleton` scope.

If you don't want to share your action beans between user's requests you should define the corresponding scope.

You can use `prototype` scope, which means a new instance is returned by the Spring each time Struts is being built an action instance.

Comment: If we integrate with spring then these actions will be maintained by spring i guess.

Comment: @RamachandrappaKalavakuri You should accept the answer if it helped you.