# If we integrate struts2 with spring then who will maintain the action instances, spring container or struts 2 container

Tags: spring, struts2

I am asking this question because of the following reasons:

Usually struts 2 action instances will get create on the request. I mean per every request new action instance will get create. But if I integrate with spring then there will be only one action instance will get create (I am not sure correct me if i am wrong). So in this case what is if I have instance variables in the action class. First user he will set that instance with some instance variables and second user may set the something. 
How it will behave at this time.

More clarification: Instance variable means, in struts 2, action forms wont be there so, your action itself work as a form to get the request parameters. First user enters something and second user enters something and both are setting to one instance action.

Comment: Even when using Spring to create them, the actions will be request-scoped.  The struts-spring plugin takes care of that for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How struts 2 will behave with spring integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464671/how-struts-2-will-behave-with-spring-integration)

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring will create a singleton instance of your action class.  In that case, depending on how your action classes are written there might be such a danger.

But you can also specify that a bean be created prototypically (`scope="prototype"`) so that a new instance of the class is created with each request.

Comment: If I create prototypically for every request spring container has to create action class instance so it will be a performance issue i guess.

Comment: This is only the case if you declare the actions as beans in a Spring context file or configuration.  But that is not necessary when integrating Struts2 with Spring.  If you leave the action out of the Spring context, then it will still be request scoped.

Comment: +1 to offset the seemingly-spurious downvote; the answer is correct.

Comment: @RamachandrappaKalavakuri Please note that S2 is *specifically* designed around the premise that actions exist *per-request*. If you deviate from that you're really on your own in terms of... well, everything. S2 is neither designed nor tested under a single-action paradigm.

Comment: @DaveNewton I down-voted because I find the answer misleading.  Using Spring with Struts2 does not default action scope to singleton.  The scope is only singleton if you define the action as a Spring bean - but this is not a necessary step.  The answer should be more clear about this distinction, and since it is not then the answer is likely to mislead many readers, hence the down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you integrated struts2 with spring, normally, the action instances are managed by spring container! this is supported by struts2 spring plugin: https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-plugin.html

Second, as the plugin doc mentioned, by default, the action bean's scope is request, this is up to the struts2, but you can change yuor action scope to other type,i.e. session,application,etc.

Comment: @Component
public class RegisterUserAction {
 
 
 private AdminUser adminUser;
 @Autowired(required=true)
 private RegisterUserService registerUserService;
 @Autowired(required=true)
 private UserContext userContext;
 
 public String execute() throws Exception {
  
  registerUserService.registerUser(adminUser);
  userContext.setCurrentUser(adminUser);
  
  return "registered";
 }} and my struts.xml configuration is as follows: <action name="registerUser" class="registerUserAction">
   <result name="registered" type="redirect">adminLoginPage</result> 
  </action>

Comment: As per above code how it will behave, for each request new action bean will get create? If yes, is this is performance issue for page rendering time? Because for every request it has to create new instance. Just for page rendering time which MVC is better Struts 2 or Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes, by default, for Struts2 one request one action instance. If Spring MVC, controller(action) is singleton, one instance for all requests.

Comment: Ad normally, request-per-controller and singleton controller are 2 strategies. It's hard to say which is better or worse.

Comment: Struts 2 actions are getting created for each request but where as Spring MVC action instance is singleton and multiple threads will access that instance. So page rendering may be good in Spring MVC.

Comment: I want to add one more here, Struts 2 with spring integration, so that time also struts 2 spring plugin tool will create multiple action instances for each request. So what is if that action is injected with services. so this time each action will get new instance of service in action instance?